# how to synch contacts from google using a push mechanism

Tags: google-contacts-api

How to get push notification for contacts changed in a google account? Is there any api similar to calendar watch? Could not find such api in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts API doesn't support push notifications. You can check the [contacts API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) and you will not find such feature mentioned.